# How can I improve notation for these matrix equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Taken from these [lecture notes](http://cerea.enpc.fr/HomePages/bocquet/teaching/assim-mb-en.pdf), on page 17, could someone explain the notation/how does one obtain equations (1.54) & (1.56)?

> Given $$x^a=x^b+K(y-Hx^b)$$
> where $x^a=\begin{pmatrix}u_{a}\\v_{a}\end{pmatrix}, x^b=\begin{pmatrix}0\\v_b\end{pmatrix},y=v_o,H=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\\end{pmatrix}$.

> $$ \begin{pmatrix}u_{a}\\v_{a}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0\\v_b\end{pmatrix} + K\Biggl(v_{0}-\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0\\v_b\end{pmatrix}\Biggr) = \begin{pmatrix}0\\v_{b}+K(v_{o}-v_{b})\end{pmatrix} \tag{1.54}$$

Wouldn't I end up with just a scalar for the middle matrix? I mean it is "obvious" from the result that it is intended to apply only for the second row. However, without knowing the final result, how does one deduce this? Even if I just blindly accept that I could add a scalar this way, wouldn't I end up adding it onto both rows?

Similarly for Eq$(1.56)$, after finding the optimal K*

> $$K^*=\frac{\sigma^{2}_{b}}{\sigma^{2}_{o}+\sigma^{2}_{b}}\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

> and substitute it back into Eq$(1.54)$:

> $$ \begin{pmatrix}u_{a}\\v_{a}\end{pmatrix} = v_b + \begin{pmatrix}0\\v_{b}+\frac{\sigma^{2}_{b}}{\sigma^{2}_{o}+\sigma^{2}_{b}}(v_{o}-v_{b})\end{pmatrix} \tag{1.56}$$

Answer (score 1):

Dimensions of matrices have to meet certain requirements for addition/subtraction and multiplication. In this case, you have $K$ being added to a length 2 vector, so that middle term must also be a length 2 vector.

However, note that when you substitute the values in, $y$ turns out to be a single scalar, and $H$ and $x^b$ end up being the dot product of two vectors, also a scalar. Now, you have $K$ times a scalar must be a length 2 vector. A scalar times a vector or matrix results in a vector or matrix of the same shape, so $K$ must be a length 2 vector.

Hopefully this explains the dimension inference aspect. The reason $K$ is that exact matrix situation is a separate question that can be answered here if you would like, but we would need more information about the situation

Comment: I think I understand your point, being that since we need a vector of length 2 for the middle term and its multiplicative term is a scalar, thus $K$ needs to be a vector of length 2. Given that, in Eq$(1.54)$, why does it make sense to end up with that final term; where K is somewhat represented like a scalar term? I guess you could argue since the first row is zero, it wouldn't matter. Even then, that notation seems weird to me. Or is that a normal thing, just that I have not encountered it before.

May I know what further information would be required to further explain this?

Comment: Actually, ignore my comment on "since the first row is zero, it wouldn't matter". An addition of $0 + K^*(scalar)$ will only result in the first row being $0$ if that is true for K too. Isn't it?